# sonatype nexus docker volume error

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

I'm triyng to install sonatype-nexus using docker and want to share docker `/opt/sonatype-work` nexus repo with host machine (linux ubuntu 14.04) `/opt/nexus`.

my dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:6

MAINTAINER Marcel Birkner <marcel.birkner@codecentric.de>

USER root
# Update the system
RUN yum -y update; \
    yum clean all

##########################################################
# Install Java JDK, SSH and other useful cmdline utilities
##########################################################
RUN yum -y install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel \
    which \
    telnet \
    unzip \
    openssh-server \
    sudo \
    openssh-clients \
    iputils \
    iproute \
    httpd-tools \
    wget \
    tar; \
    yum clean all
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/jre

##########################################################
# Install Nexus
##########################################################
RUN mkdir -p /opt/sonatype-nexus /opt/sonatype-work
RUN wget -O /tmp/nexus-latest-bundle.tar.gz http://www.sonatype.org/downloads/nexus-latest-bundle.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf /tmp/nexus-latest-bundle.tar.gz -C /opt/sonatype-nexus --strip-components=1
RUN useradd --user-group --system --home-dir /opt/sonatype-nexus nexus

ADD nexus.xml /opt/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/nexus.xml

RUN chown -R nexus:nexus /opt/sonatype-work /opt/sonatype-nexus

ENV NEXUS_WEBAPP_CONTEXT_PATH /nexus
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > /opt/start-nexus.sh
RUN echo "su -c \"/opt/sonatype-nexus/bin/nexus console\" - nexus" >> /opt/start-nexus.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/start-nexus.sh
VOLUME /opt/sonatype-work
CMD ["/opt/start-nexus.sh"]
EXPOSE 8081
```

when i build this image (build succeed) :

```
docker build -t sonatype/nexus .
```

then i run it by this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v /opt/nexus:/opt/sonatype-work sonatype/nexus
```

it started and stopped immediately 
Error showed (`docker logs nexus`):

```
nexus_1 | jvm 1    | Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/sonatype-work/nexus
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:383) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:630) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:734) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:720) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(DirSupport.java:146) ~[na:na]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.util.file.DirSupport.mkdir(DirSupport.java:162) ~[na:na]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.WebappBootstrap.contextInitialized(WebappBootstrap.java:115) ~[na:na]
nexus_1 | jvm 1    |    ... 16 common frames omitted
nexus_1 | wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

and if i removed `VOLUME /opt/sonatype-nexus` from dockerfile it works fine.

do you have any idea what might caused this problem? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you bind-mount a host directory in a container, the files and directories in the host directory take precedence and are mounted over the files already present inside the container's image. In other words, they "mask" what's underneath in the container.

Bind-mounts keep their permissions of the directory that's present on the host, and if no directory is present on the host, Docker creates it, using `root:root` as owner.

Looking at the `useradd nexus` in your Dockerfile, I suspect that `start-nexus.sh` runs nexus with that user, so it may not have permissions on the bind-mounted directory (which is owned by root). You can fix this by `chowning` the directory to the numeric uid/gid of `nexus` inside the container.

To get the `uid` / `gid` of that user, start the container interactively;

```
docker run -it --rm sonatype/nexus bash
```

And inside that shell request the uid/gid:

```
id nexus
```

Which gives you something like:

```
uid=123(nexus) gid=456(nexus) groups=456(nexus)
```

Now exit the container (`exit`), and chown the directory on the host, using the uid/gid;

```
sudo chown -R 123:456 /opt/nexus
```

**Some things I noticed**

It looks like you're building your own custom version of the sonatype nexus image, but use the same name as the official image (`sonatype/nexus`). I'd recommend not doing that, and giving it your own name (e.g. `mycompany/nexus`); this prevents confusion, and also prevents your own
image to be overwritten with the official image if someone runs `docker pull sonatype/nexus`.

Is there any reason for not using the official image? In general it's recommended to use the official images, as they are maintained by the maintainers of the software (sonatype in this case), so should give you an up-to-date (and maintained) version of the software; https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus/

Comment: indeed it was question of chowning my host directory `/opt/nexus` should have same owner as docker user, thanks @thaJeztah.
Finally i switched to the official image `sonatype/nexus` the nexus uid is 200 as mentioned in dockerfile so all i have to do is to change owner of my directory and it works fine.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Fixed my problem too (permission denied, IllegalStateException when running the sonatype/nexus:oss Docker definition).

Answer (score 0):

beware of selinux

run `setenforce 0` and if it helps, consider to disable it permanently by setting
`SELINUX=disabled`
in
`/etc/sysconfig/selinux`
config file.