# Error while mounting host directory in Nexus Docker

Tags: docker, nexus3

I am using the following command to run my container

```
docker run -d -p 9001:8081 --name nexus -v /Users/user.name/dockerVolume/nexus:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

Container starts and fail immediately. with the following logs

> mkdir: cannot create directory '../sonatype-work/nexus3/log':
>   Permission denied
>
> mkdir: cannot create directory
>   '../sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp': Permission denied
>
> Java HotSpot(TM)
>   64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file
>   ../sonatype-work/nexus3/log/jvm.log due to No such file or directory

I was following this [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/) to set it up
I have given said permission to nexus directory.

I also tried the following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405434/sonatype-nexus-docker-volume-error) but that didn't help me either.
I was still getting the same error.

Docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac47 (21805)

[EDIT]
I did made changes to the ownership of my nexus folder on my host

```
sudo chown -R 200 ~/dockerVolume/nexus
```

Comment: Provide Dockerfile, do not just share link.

Comment: This is from docker hub and I have just pulled it in. I do not have access to dockerfile and they have not added it from github. I did quick check to figure  it out but was not able to. I am using **docker pull sonatype/nexus3**

Answer (score 18):

In my ubuntu server I had to perform:

```
chown -R 200:200 path/to/directory
```

Not only 200, but **200:200**

Comment: After upgrading 3.37 to 3.41 I had the same problem. Until that it was working with root group. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 14):

If you have this problem trying to run Nexus3 inside of Kubernetes cluster, you should set UID with *initContainers*. Just add it to your *spec*:

```
initContainers:
- name: volume-mount-hack
  image: busybox
  command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 200:200 /nexus-data"]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: <your nexus pvc volume name>
    mountPath: /nexus-data
```

Answer (score 1):

That **[Dockerfile](https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/master/Dockerfile)** is available, in the repo [`sonatype/docker-nexus3`](https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3).

And mounting a volume is [documented as](https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3#persistent-data):

> ### Mount a host directory as the volume.
>
> This is not portable, as it relies on the directory existing with correct permissions on the host. However it can be useful in certain situations where this volume needs to be assigned to certain specific underlying storage.

```
$ mkdir /some/dir/nexus-data && chown -R 200 /some/dir/nexus-data
$ docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v /some/dir/nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3
```

So don't forget to do, *before* your `docker run`:

```
chown -R 200 /Users/user.name/dockerVolume/nexus
```

Comment: I did made these changes but am still getting this error. Also I looked it up in SO and found one post (which I have listed above) id nexus given me uid as 200 only.

Comment: @Anunay Then switch to the recommended approach, and create a data volume: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes

Comment: OR probably try to create an extended Dockerfile & add required permissions using that.

Comment: Will try that out as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj10f.png)

Nexus Repository stores its data in the **/sonatype-work** directory by default [(check this link)](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation-and-upgrades/directories)

so instead of **/nexus-data** try to use **/sonatype-work** for exp:

`docker run -p 8081:8081 -v /data/nexus:/sonatype-work --name nexus -d sonatype/nexus3`

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you